# Error 945 Database cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space. See the SQL Server error log for details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-engine

While trying to access databases, logins, etc in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2, below error is always popping up. I browsed over google to find out a solution but those resolutions did not solved below issue. I have sufficient permissions and have enough disk space. When clicked on any entity in Object Explorer of SQL Management Studio the below exception appears.

[image]

Comment: Look at the msdb properties->Files>-Autogrowth/Maxsize to see if Enable Autogrowth is ticked.

Comment: I further found that database 'msdb' has 'Recovery Pending' as message displayed just next to database.
How do I perform this Recovery on msdb database?

Comment: Do you have a backup of msdb?

Comment: No. I don't have a backup

Answer (score 3):

Once you made the space, close your Management Studio and goto services.msc and restart the SQL Server () service, that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have also received same error, and DB Size in Plesk is showing **0Bytes**.
After checking in SQL Server, I found that in-front of my database showing > **(Recovery Pending)** message just next to database.

In Plesk, I have used **"Repair Database" option Forcefully**, and after that my DB is showing exact DB Size = 100MB, where previously it was showing 0Bytes.

Hope it helps anyone, getting this error in Plesk hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these options:

- Add more hard drive space by removing unnecessary files or add the new hard drive.
- Check the Autogrow
- Check the database account permission
- MDF and LDF shouldn't be marked as read-only on OS file system level

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the MDF file was deleted.

check the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.[sqlserver edittion]\MSSQL\DATA` to see if the .mdf file is in place